# VMware shutdown host from a virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machines

There is any way to shutdown my host from one of my virtual machine? I've an host with 2 VM one with linux and one with windows server and I would stop entire host from one of this. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to ask why you want to do this. You could:

1. On the VM touch a file on a file mounted from the host.
2. Have a script (powershell or something) which shuts the host down when it detects the file touched in step 1.

or

invoke a web enabled UPS to send a shutdown via a curl command.

These limks might help you with PowerShell:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849839.aspx

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/20cfc9af-d45a-4bcf-a79a-c7844f996984/powershell-testpath-if-a-file-exists-within-a-folder?forum=ITCG

Comment: The first option. Is possible?

Comment: If you have a host filesystem mounted then yes.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849839.aspx
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/20cfc9af-d45a-4bcf-a79a-c7844f996984/powershell-testpath-if-a-file-exists-within-a-folder?forum=ITCG